# How to generate SAS toke for blob storage in dart language

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, shared-access-signatures

I'm currently trying to generate SAS token for blob file in dart language. I took reference from a python code also. In python generate_sas_token() function requires policy id for azure blob storage. where to get this
[image: policy_id]

This the info I have, Or is there any other way to generate other than generate_sas_token() SDK in python. The reason s I want to create SAS token via dart only. So that I need a flow or method to generate SAS.

Thanks in advance

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String encode_signature(String signature){
  return signature.replaceAll(':', '%3A');
}

String generateSasToken(String accountName, String accountKey, String containerName, String blobName, int expiryHours) {
  var ttl = DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: expiryHours)).millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
  
  var stringToSign = "r\n${DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").format(DateTime.now().toUtc())}\n${DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: expiryHours)).toUtc())}\n/$accountName/$containerName/$blobName\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
  
  var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, base64.decode(accountKey));
  var signature = base64.encode(hmacSha256.convert(utf8.encode(stringToSign)).bytes);
  
  var queryParams = {
    'sp': 'r',
    'st': DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").format(DateTime.now().toUtc()),
    'se': DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: expiryHours)).toUtc()),
    'sv': '2022-11-02',
    'sr': 'b',
    'sig': encode_signature(signature),//Uri.encodeComponent(signature).replaceAll('%3A', ':'), // Encode the signature component
  };

  var queryString = Uri(queryParameters: queryParams).query;

  return queryString;
}

void main() {
  var accountName = "account_name";
  var accountKey = "accountkey";
  var containerName = "azure-webjobs-hosts";
  var blobName = "0_12d6fa4202ac42bdbc33923c413c68ff_1.json";
  var expiryHours = 168;

  var sasToken = generateSasToken(accountName, accountKey, containerName, blobName, expiryHours);
  print(sasToken);
}
```

this is the code Im running now Im able to get but the only issue is
This is the SAS generated in azure portal -

> sp=r&st=2024-03-11T06:25:18Z&se=2024-03-11T14:25:18Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=sMX853JrU%2BkgAGgKTXS1XQRvFoh6%2BQQ3jNWRnG8LWVI%3D

This is generated by above code -

> sp=r&st=2024-03-14T11%3A56%3A00&se=2024-03-21T11%3A56%3A00&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=jPsFzl2RoTJNGbMNg%252FwcT1oi%252FyIIBjFJeps1pJyMCGc%253D

Instead of colon ":" I'm getting "%3A". Even though I used replace all function.
What could be the issue?

The token is generating but
[image]

this the timezone in azure portal
but when I generate SAS in azure portal it give
the following timezone

[image]

What would be the issue. The time difference is 5 hours 27 mins approx (minutes variable)

**Next issue**

I'am able to generate valid SAS token for blob. I used the same for container, but getting 403 error I thought token generation is the problem but later tried with azure portal generated sas token for container still getting the same 403 how it is possible?
below  is the code I used to get container list

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final String folderURL = 'https://myblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts?sp=r&st=2024-03-22T07:21:47Z&se=2024-03-22T15:21:47Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=Eg%2B04lD3EWLo2wGocU9mqNjKwqKmo04zSCH0Dbsjqlg%3D';//$storageBlobEndpoint/$containerName?$sasToken';

  // Make a request to list the blobs within the folder
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(folderURL));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<dynamic> blobs = json.decode(response.body);
    print("Files in the folder:");
    for (var blob in blobs) {
      print(blob['name']);
    }
  } else {
    print('Failed to fetch data: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: please share the code which you have tried

Comment: @Sai Raise it in new thread.

Comment: yes did, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78205634/sas-token-for-azure-storage-container-failed-403-erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below dart generates a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for accessing Azure Blob Storage resources. SAS tokens provide restricted access to resources in your storage account, with specified permissions and time limits.

**generateSasToken method:**

it generates a SAS token based on the provided parameters such as resourceUri, key, permissions, sr, and expiryHours.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

class SasTokenGenerator {
  String generateSasToken({
    required String resourceUri,
    required String key,
    required String permissions,
    required String sr, // Added parameter for the resource type
    int expiryHours = 24,
  }) {
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.now(); // Adjusting start time by 5 minutes for clock skew
    DateTime expiry = startTime.add(Duration(hours: expiryHours));
    String formattedStartTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'Z'").format(startTime);
    String formattedExpiry = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'Z'").format(expiry);

    String stringToSign = 'sp=$permissions\nst=$formattedStartTime\nse=$formattedExpiry\nspr=https\nsv=2022-11-02\nsr=$sr\n$resourceUri'; // Include sr parameter
    String signature = _generateSignature(stringToSign, key);

    return 'sp=$permissions&st=$formattedStartTime&se=$formattedExpiry&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=$sr&sig=$signature'; // Include sr parameter
  }

  String _generateSignature(String input, String key) {
    var keyBytes = utf8.encode(key);
    var inputBytes = utf8.encode(input);
    var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, keyBytes);
    var digest = hmacSha256.convert(inputBytes);
    return Uri.encodeComponent(base64.encode(digest.bytes));
  }
}

void main() {
  String resourceUri = "https://account_name.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/example.txt";
  String key = "accountkey";
  String permissions = "r"; // r for read, w for write, d for delete, etc.
  String sr = "b"; // Specify the resource type: b for Blob service, c for Container service, etc.
  int expiryHours = 24; // Expiry duration in hours

  SasTokenGenerator generator = SasTokenGenerator();
  String sasToken = generator.generateSasToken(
    resourceUri: resourceUri,
    key: key,
    permissions: permissions,
    sr: sr, // Pass sr parameter
    expiryHours: expiryHours,
  );

  print('Generated SAS Token: $sasToken');
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Failed to fetch data: 403

Comment: for account key I used key1 from this place storage account->access policy-> key1. Is this correct

Comment: correct about the access policy. error 403 might occur because of the time difference in sas UTC time and in normal we have ist time. if you have a problem another way is to use the rest API URL in Dart and convert the rest API to dart [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakeanalytics/storage-accounts/list-sas-tokens?view=rest-datalakeanalytics-2016-11-01&tabs=HTTP)

Comment: I tried changing the UTC time and still the error reminds same

Comment: Can you specify what you said confused a bit about REST API. I'm trying to generate dynamically instead of generating sas each time manually. once I get the sas I will read the file using http.get(). This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: with rest api it also generates time only. I will also check with http.get()  sai

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I try any other ways to generate dynamically SAS for now. I also checked the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas code seems fine.

Comment: Ok also check with check with http.get() .

Comment: Hi @sampath it worked I followed the document and did some changes for signed parameters. My doubt is, to generate token for container also same procedure right. My problem is I want to print the multiple files placed in single container but the blobs are stored like this Container -> a folder -> blob files.

Comment: Yes,  The procedure for generating a SAS token for accessing a container follows the same steps outlined in the document for generating SAS tokens for other resources such as blobs, queues, tables, or files. Once you have generated the SAS token for the container, you can use it to access the blobs stored within the container