# SAS token for azure storage container failed 403 error

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Trying to list the files stored in blob storage container. Generated SAS url and used the following program.but getting error

> Error - Failed to fetch data: 403

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final String folderURL = 'https://myblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts?sp=r&st=2024-03-22T07:21:47Z&se=2024-03-22T15:21:47Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=Eg%2B04lD3EWLo2wGocU9mqNjKwqKmo04zSCH0Dbsjqlg%3D';//$storageBlobEndpoint/$containerName?$sasToken';

  // Make a request to list the blobs within the folder
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(folderURL));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<dynamic> blobs = json.decode(response.body);
    print("Files in the folder:");
    for (var blob in blobs) {
      print(blob['name']);
    }
  } else {
    print('Failed to fetch data: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: 403 = Forbidden --> not authenticated --> need login or token

Comment: To list the files url should be `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&<sastoken>` refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=microsoft-entra-id

Comment: https://storageaccname.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts?restype=container&comp=list&sp=r&st=2024-03-22T11:34:54Z&se=2024-03-22T19:34:54Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=kDZhsrmfmwRYXdij8ES9SRZD2ICzEu2zJ5gweqFrg3s%3D still 403 error sas token generated in azure portal

Comment: Check the below answer.

Comment: Is the `storageaccount` name is correct?

Comment: this is my actual url https://deviceblob.blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts?restype=container&comp=list&sp=r&st=2024-03-22T11:34:54Z&se=2024-03-22T19:34:54Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=kDZhsrQfmwRYXdij8ES9SRZD2ICzEu2zJ5gweqFrg3s%3D

Comment: Sorry, I figured out In your `sas token` permission should be `sp=rl`(Read and list) to list the blobs. In your Url it is read only.

Comment: Hope this address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Error - Failed to fetch data: 403
> ```

Even when I tried with the same Container URL, I got the same error.

**Error:**
[image]

The above error occurred due to using an incorrect URL, which you passed to make the request.

To list the blobs, you need to use the URL below.

**Request:**

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&<Your sas token>
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[List Blobs (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)

Comment: still same this is a new one 
https://jein02npeasuaeztrst01.blob.core.windows.net/blob-device?restype=container&comp=list&sp=r&st=2024-03-22T12:06:06Z&se=2024-03-22T20:06:06Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=oY7xNrsgVtRzFp1ApMSDllMNZmhNOXUnFxamF%2FeR%2Bu8%3D

Comment: Still in your sastoken permission is in `sp=r` it should be sp=`rl`.